# regexp problem, the dot selects all text

Tags: javascript, regex

I use some jquery to highlight search results. For some reason if i enter a basis dot, all of the text get selected. I use regex and replace to wrap the results in a tag to give the found matches a color.

the code that i use

```
 var pattern = new.RegExp('('+$.unique(text.split(" ")).join("|")+")","gi");
```

how can i prevent that the dot selects all text, so i want to leave the point out of the code(the dot has no power)

Comment: That's not a problem, that's how regex works. I can't help but saying - RTFM!

Comment: In a regular expression a `.` matches anything.  It sounds like you don't want the original text to be treated as a pattern at all, in which case you need to escape any regexp special chars in text.

Comment: okay, well if understand regex i would read the manual, but i cant find anything about this on the web so that why i asked it here ;)

Comment: so you say its normal that a dot selects all text?

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking here, but there are a ton of good resources for regex on the web. Here's [one tutorial I referred to](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) when I was first learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get there by doing this:

```
var pattern = new.RegExp('('+$.unique(text.replace('.', '\\.').split(" ")).join("|")+")","gi");
```

The idea here is that you're attempting to escape the period, which acts as a wild card in regex.

Comment: aha okay this works, didnt thought that is this easy ;)  thanks

Comment: I think you might want to use `.replace(/\./g, '\\.')` instead. I believe your method will only replace the first match.

Comment: yes you are right, entering more dots will still select some text, thanks Bryan, this works perfect

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all special RegExp characters (except for `|` since you're using that to join the terms) with their escaped version so you won't get unwanted matches or syntax errors:

```
var str = $.unique(text.split(" ")).join("|"),
    pattern;
str = str.replace(/[\\\.\+\*\?\^\$\[\]\(\)\{\}\/\'\#\:\!\=]/ig, "\\$&");
pattern = new RegExp('('+str+')', 'gi');
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot is [supposed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) to match all text (almost everything, really). If you want to match a period, you can just escape it as `\.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a period in your RegExp it's supposed to match any character besides newline characters. If you don't want that functionality you need to escape the period.

Example RegExp with period escaped `/word\./`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the text you're putting into the regex, so that special characters don't have unwanted meanings.  My code is based on some from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote:491):

```
var words = $.unique(text.split(" ")).join("|");
words = words.replace(/[.\\+*?\[\^\]$(){}=!<>|:\\-]/h, '\\$&'); // escape regex special chars

var pattern = new RegExp('(' + words + ")","gi");
```

This escapes the following characters: `.\+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:-` with a backslash `\` so you can safely insert them into your `new RegExp` construction.